# N2O canister getting stuck in whipping siphon?

Tags: whipped-cream

this is the first time I tried to make homemade whipped cream, so I bought a new whipped cream siphon and some N2O cartridges, and the first time I tried to use it, all worked well and I made a bit of whipped cream. When I unscrewed the canister cover though (the one the canister goes in to be screwed onto the bottle), I found that it was stuck inside and it took me about 15 minutes to get out with pliers. (Note: It also took a surprising amount of force to screw in in the first place)

I looked up some videos on how to make whipped cream, and they show people just shaking the canister out of the cover once they're done. There's no way I can do this, as when I insert it into the cover and just slightly press it in with my thumb, it takes a lot of shaking to get out. It simply gets stuck there almost immediately.

Do I have the wrong type of cartridge, or is there a step I am missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like the error was when putting the first cartridge in. Either the siphon has a production fault, or you forced it in incorrectly and it is now damaged (the thread?). Somebody will have to take a look at it, we can't answer that here (Neither can we know if you have the wrong type of cartridge, since you don't mention brand names and type numbers).

Comment: Instructions unclear, canister stuck in syphon.

Comment: Have you tried another batch of cartridges? Or another gas? My guess is that the syphon may be faulty rather than the cartridges although that can happen I suppose. Wrong type cartridges are also not too likely to have only slightly different dimensions; they are typically so different that there would be no way of putting one into the wrong equipment. In my somewhat limited experience, the cartridge always drops out readily without any help. How much gas is in the cartridge as printed on the box?